# i was just trying to learn dart when i tried running it showed an error saying that Error: Not found: 'dart:svg' ? so waht shhould i do now

Tags: flutter, dart

PS C:\Users\91812\Desktop\hellodartwars\dart_application_1> dart "c:\Users\91812\Desktop\hellodartwars\dart_application_1\web\main.dart"
web/main.dart:1:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:svg'
import 'dart:svg';

Comment: Did you try to import 'dart:svg' ? No 'dart:svg', so you got an error.

Comment: Can you share your code?